# Infinispan cache store file migrate to Redis

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis, infinispan

Actually we use Infinisoan as cache server, and we want to migrate this to Redis, after the necessary configuration between my application and redis server I want to migrate also this file to redis configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:9.4"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:9.4 http://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-9.4.xsd">
    <cache-container>
        <local-cache name="v1_key1" statistics="true">
            <!-- 4 hours -->
            <expiration lifespan="14400000"/>
            <memory>
                <object strategy="LIRS" size="18"/>
            </memory>
        </local-cache>
     </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

I tried to use:

```
spring:
  cache:
    type: redis
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
  caches-ttl:
    v1_key1: 0 # zero for test
```

But this create the cache and for one time, so if I call my endpoint again it will use the cache, which is not what I expect.

Is there an equivalent of this configuration with redis ?